# Using XML to save properties of objects

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, file, flash, save

Is there any way of saving the existence, position and properties of a `MovieClip` on the stage without typing in the name of the `MovieClip` itself? I ask because there are several different `MovieClips` the user can add to the stage and move around so I was wondering if there was a way of basically saving the location and properties of all objects currently on the stage or on a certain `Sprite` layer that I have created?

Answer (score 0):

Save the properties to an array or a set of arrays, one for each MovieClip. Then store the arrays as SharedObjects.

Comment: Are there any examples of how to do this? I'm not well versed in using SharedObjects.